# Watch WWDC session videos on Android

Tags: macos, ios

Does anyone know how to watch Apple WWDC session videos on Android (not the keynote)? They are like Google I/O sessions videos but on Apple platforms.

On the Mac, one can watch it with Safari (not Chrome). And on iOS, Apple has built native apps for that. I didn't find WWDC apps in Play Store, neither does Apple allow watching the videos in Chrome.

For example, [WWDC 2013](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fwwdc%2Fvideos%2F&ei=dwYjUuWBBpSqhAfNtoHIDA&usg=AFQjCNEaOkudlv1hcD0wTnr1PomgGdU6VA&bvm=bv.51495398,d.ZG4), [WWDC 2012](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fvideos%2Fwwdc%2F2012%2F&ei=rwYjUuaXDseThgfZrYHICw&usg=AFQjCNEOKpUoNtbZK1YRSRB-gUTMXnwYEg&bvm=bv.51495398,d.ZG4).

I'm an iOS developer who just bought a Nexus 7 2013 for fun. So I do watch WWDC session videos :)

Comment: It might be easier to help if you say what is special about these videos or website that stops them working in Chrome.

Comment: I'm not sure, the links are above. Maybe it's checking HTTP header for browser?

Comment: It certainly appears to be a deliberate choice on Apple's part not to allow other browsers. You might have better luck trying to find a pirated copy with Bittorrent or similar.